# Parse API: Rest request for relation data

Tags: json, rest, parse-platform

I'm using the Parse API. I have a class, Category, that contains a field, subcategories. This field is a relation that points to other instances of the class Category. I want to perform a Rest request that retrieves the subcategories for a particular category, but I can't figure out how to make it work. Here's the Url I'm using right now:

```
https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Category?where={"$relatedTo":{"object":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"Category","objectID":"dkFGBAL5A7"},"key":"subcategories"}}
```

The objectID is for the "parent" Category that I want to get subcategories for. However, I get the following error response:

```
{
    "code": 102,
    "error": "a valid pointer is needed for RelatedTo operator"
}
```

I know that the objectID is correct. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"objectId" not "objectID". It's always the little things...