# Relationships in Parse for Android

Tags: android

I am in the process of creating an Android app (using Parse as the back end). The app will allow users to post images to a group of people and users within the group can like or dislike the images). How would I set this kind of relationship in Parse?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse API: Rest request for relation data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18662097/parse-api-rest-request-for-relation-data)

Comment: Hi Abhinav, your link doesn't answer my question. Thanks for the help.